# How to upgrade pandas from version 0.17.1 to higher version?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pandas

Need to upgrade version of pandas.
I installed pandas via: pip install -U pandas
The installed version of pandas was 0.17.1 and I need version 0.18.0.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of question is easily google-able.

```
# if you want the latest version available
pip install pandas --upgrade
# or if you want to specify a version
pip install pandas==<higher-version>
```

Comment: It should be:
`pip install pandas==0.18.0`
instead of 
`pip install pandas=0.18.0`